# How to sum the number of correct answers in loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am having problems at the `sum =`  and `cout` part inside the loop. I have to write a program which shows how many numbers there are in an interval which when divided by seven has a residue of 3.

For example: if I put starting point (a) as 1 and ending point (b) as 30 on screen shows up 3,10,17 and 24. But I need to make the program not show which numbers have the residue of 3, but how many of such numbers are in that interval (at thise example a number 4 should appear on screen).

```
cout << "Iveskite intervalo pradzia: "; cin >> a;
cout << "Iveskite intervalo pabaiga: "; cin >> b;

for (i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
    if (i % 7 == 3)
    sum =
    cout << i << endl;
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increment `sum` each time you have such a number that match `i % 7 == 3`.
First you need to initialize `sum` to 0. You can display `sum` at the end of you program after the loop

```
cout << "Iveskite intervalo pradzia: "; cin >> a;
cout << "Iveskite intervalo pabaiga: "; cin >> b;

int sum = 0;

for (i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
    if (i % 7 == 3)
    {  
        ++sum;
        cout << i << endl; // Not mandatory if you don't want to display the actual number
    }
}
cout << sum << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although the "int sum = 0;" part was not necessary as I already had it written down, just above the "cout" sentences :D

Comment: I did! Also how could I contact you? I have some more questions that I cannot find answers to :/